# Cloudant basic authentication not working after setting up cloudflare virtual host

Tags: virtualhost, basic-authentication, cloudflare, cloudant

I'm using Cloudant as my database, and [I've correctly set it up with Cloudflare as a virtual host](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/create-a-custom-domain-for-cloudant-using-cloudflare-e32f11b33967) so instead of having a randomly generated subdomain to my database like this:

`f8b3f1f4-b695-4806-someting-fre-bluemix.cloudant.com`

I got it in under my custom domain like this:

`db.example.com`

I've correctly set the SSL certificate and everything is perfectly good.

The problem now is that on the custom domain I can't authenticate (using basic auth) to my DB using the username and the password I use on the randomly generated domain.

on the custom domain (db.example.com), I get this error:

```
{
     "error": "unauthorized",
     "reason": "Name or password is incorrect."
}
```

while on the original domain (f8b3f1f4-b695-4806-someting-fre-bluemix.cloudant.com) the basic auth works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant auth needs some way to figure out your username, which it normally does by using the subdomain, which is also your account name and login. Normally, this is added by the load balancer which knows about the subdomain, but you may have to add it manually when using a virtual host (I've never tried). Try adding a header "X-Cloudant-User: f8b3f1f4-b695-4806-someting-fre-bluemix" (or whatever your account is) to your request and see if that changes anything.